# Prevent integer values to set boolean parameter in ASP.NET Web API model binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an ASP.NET Web API in which a method takes below model as an input parameter

```
public InputModel
{
    int Id {get; set;}
    bool? IsTrue {get; set;}
}
```

It works with true and false value. I tried to check how it behaves for non-boolean values. So I provided inputs and got some results

> isTrue = 0 -> model set to false
>   isTrue = 1 -> model set to true
>   isTrue = 2 -> model set to true
>   isTrue = -1 -> model set to true

This is something that I didn't expect. The model is set to true for all non-zero integers

How can I configure the model binder to set values only on boolean inputs and not on integer inputs(maybe give some validation error)?

Comment: If the value can be more than either `0` or `1`, maybe a boolean is not the right type?

Comment: I was just trying to see how boolean behaves for a non boolean input. Since the API will be public and anyone can send any value, it is my responsibility to at least validate the input. The above scenario might be valid in some cases but not in mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the set method of the property as follows:

```
public InputModel
{
    int Id {get; set;}
    private bool istrue;
    bool? Istrue
    {
        get
        {
            return istrue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.GetType() == typeof(bool))
            {
                istrue = value;
            }
            else
            {
                istrue = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will set the property to false for every non-boolean input and I cannot know whether the false was set because of non-boolean input or the client has explicitly sent "false" as data. One modification I can think of is setting some other property on falsy of type check and use that as logic for a bad request. But this will be a pain if there many boolean inputs.