# Avoid bind any number to bool property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have simple ASP.NET Core WebApi with model

```
public class Model
{
    public bool? Value {get; set;}
}
```

and endpoint

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] Model model)
```

When I make a POST request with body

```
{
   "Value" : 7676
}
```

or

```
{
   "Value" : 2955454545645645645645645645654534534540    
}
```

then `model.Value == true`

How to avoid this? I need some error in this case, because `7676` is not the Boolean value.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56132879/asp-net-core-model-binder-accepts-random-integer-for-boolean-types) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798050/prevent-integer-values-to-set-boolean-parameter-in-asp-net-web-api-model-binding), but solution is not fit for me, because I have a many models in different projects (so, it will hard to add  JsonConverter attribute, from answer, to all properties)

Also, I'm looking for any docs that describes this behavior.

Comment: Write a custom model binder and use that

Comment: You should be getting error like "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]. Path: $.Value" when you try to post invalid Json property value. Which version of asp.net core are you using?

Comment: @vendettamit yes, I also think so, but behavior is like I described. ASP.NET Core 2.2

Comment: @Milney could you please help with custom model binder? I have a lot of models, can I create binder for bool properties in all models? I've tried this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2 but always got `ValueProviderResult.None`

Comment: Create a custom `MyBookConverter` deriving from `JsonConverter` and then register it `services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => { options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new MyBoolConverter());});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve it by creating a custom JsonConverter. The documenation for the same can be found [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)

The reason for this behavior has got to do with the way JSON.NET or `System.Text.JSON` deserializes types. Since 123 can be converted to `boolean` true, deserialization is successful. It considers it to be true or false depending upon the integer value until you explicitly define a JsonConverter as below that checks the token being read is actually boolean.

**If you aren't using Newtonsoft. You make use of `System.Text.Json`** You can follow this page to [create a custom JSON converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to)

```
public class OnlyBoolean : JsonConverter
{
     readonly JsonSerializer defaultSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

     public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
     {
         return objectType == typeof(bool);
     }

     public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
     {
         switch (reader.TokenType)
         {

             case JsonToken.Boolean:
             {
                 return defaultSerializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
             }
             case JsonToken.String:
             {
                 if (reader.Value?.ToString() == "true" || reader.Value?.ToString() == "false")
                      return defaultSerializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
                 else
                      throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Token \"{0}\" of type {1} is not a boolean type", reader.Value, reader.TokenType));
            }
            case JsonToken.Integer:
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value) == 1 || Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value) == 0)
                    return defaultSerializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
                else
                    throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Token \"{0}\" of type {1} is not a boolean type", reader.Value, reader.TokenType));
            }
            default:
                      throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Value\"{0}\" of type {1} is not a boolean type", reader.Value, reader.TokenType));
          }
      }

      public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

      public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
      {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
}
```

and then decorate your model as:

```
public class Model
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(OnlyBoolean))]
    public bool? Value {get; set;}
}
```

or register it globally in Startup

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => { options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new OnlyBoolean());});
```

Comment: @Chebur I have edited it to accept "true" "false" 1 and 0 also as valid inputs. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Great answer. Do you know if this has a asp.net framework equivalent?